# Escaping multiline strings in Mathematica

Tags: string-manipulation, input-forms

I want to assign long multi-line strings in Mathematica.  Is there a way of delineating a block without having to escape each instance of '"' with '\"' and each line ending with '\'?

i.e. In other languages we can do this:
'''
mu very long multi line 
string with "quotes"
'''

Comment: Not sure if I understand .... ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbyua.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the closest to Python's triple quotes is a `TextCell`. You can enter it as follows:

[image: enter text]

Here I opened an *inline cell* after typing the input `a =`. This is done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> (or going to the `Insert` menu, then to `Typesetting...` and `Start Inline Cell`).

In the light orange highlighted box, you can type any text you want in a natural way, just like in Python between `"""`.

Comment: I hit a snag when trying to use the variable 'a' in your example above in a function that expects a string.  In this case,  I want to call 
result = REvaluate[a]
But I get an error because REvaluate expects a string, not a TextCell.
Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out from one of your other posts.  I used
a = ToString@@ Ctrl-9 my text here Ctrl-0